# How does one take a fully white png with some transparency, and recolor it partially?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have this png sprite sheet of clouds. I'm perfectly capable of slicing up the spritesheet, and putting a single cloud into a canvas context. But what if I wanted to modify the image of that cloud?
What if I wanted to tint it with yellow on the left? With some type of radial gradient. Those things should be possible, right? Where the radial gradient only affects the white cloud pixels but only as much as they are transparent.
What is this called? what do I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then re-write your question and you might get answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [**compositing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing), and yes, it is very doable with the Canvas2D API which offers a [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property with a few different modes.

Here is a simple ES6 example using a [fully white + alpha sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvewl.png), on which we will draw a radialGradient.

```js
(async() => {
  const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  const clouds = getCloudsObjects(30);
  const sheet = await loadImage('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvewl.png');
  ctx.filter = 'blur(2px)';

  const cloud_grad = initGrad('yellow', 'red');
  const sky_grad = initGrad('#300c46', 'green');
  anim();

  function anim() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    clouds.forEach(updateAndDrawSprite);
    // draw only on non transparent pixels, keeping the alpha info
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
    drawGrad(cloud_grad);

    if (bg.checked) {
      // draw behind everything ?
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
      drawGrad(sky_grad);
    }

    // reset gCO
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }

  function initGrad(col1, col2) {
    const grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, c.height, 0, 0, c.height, c.width * 1.6);
    grad.addColorStop(0, col1);
    grad.addColorStop(0.7, col2);
    return grad;
  }

  function drawGrad(grad) {
    ctx.fillStyle = grad;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  }

  function updateAndDrawSprite(obj) {
    obj.update();
    ctx.drawImage(sheet, obj.ox, obj.oy, obj.ow, obj.oh, obj.x, obj.y, obj.w, obj.h);
  }

  function getCloudsObjects(nbOfClouds) {
    const arr = [];
    const W = 64,
      h = 16,
      w = 16,
      max = w / W;
    for (let i = 0; i < nbOfClouds; i++) {
      let s = Math.random() * (c.height / h);
      arr[i] = {
        ox: Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) * w,
        oy: 0,
        oh: h,
        ow: w,
        x: Math.random() * c.width,
        y: Math.random() * c.height,
        w: s * w,
        h: s * h,
        speed: Math.random() - .5,
        update: function() {
          this.x += this.speed;
          this.y += this.speed / 2;
          if (this.x > c.width)
            this.x = -this.w;
          if (this.y > c.height)
            this.y = -this.h;
          if (this.x < -this.w)
            this.x = c.width;
          if (this.y < -this.h)
            this.y = c.height;
        }
      };
    }
    return arr;
  }

  function loadImage(url) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = e => res(img);
      img.onerror = e => rej(img);
      img.src = url;
    });
  }

})();
```

```css
label {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500"></canvas>
<label>draw background <input type="checkbox" id="bg"></label>
```

Comment: And since it has been a long time I wanted to do something like this, https://jsfiddle.net/9ds36xoz/ even though it's still very incomplete and that colors scales should be reviewed...

Comment: Wow. this is amazing. thank you for sharing. I am just now getting back to this. I appreciate this very much. So much insight